# unbound variables in perl regexes

Tags: regex, perl

I have a bunch of lines like these:

```
John Smith
Jane Doe
Dr. Bruce Wayne
```

and I would like to put the names into a csv file with two columns: title and full name.
I'm using the regex for this: `/(\w*\. )?(.*)/`, then I print `"$1;$2"`. The problem is that in names without a title, perl complains about an uninitialized value $1. How do I make it just use an empty string?

Comment: That makes no sense, Either your regex matches, then both `$1` and `$2` are bound, or it doesn't, then neither are bound. (Well, `$1` might be bound from the previous regex you used, but that's an irrelevant value and no better than an undefined one.) In any way, if the match fails, you shouldn't be using `$1` *or* `$2`! m42's answer shows how to make the regex always match.

Comment: @Kilian: I know, I forgot a `?` after the first group. I still had to put the `|` in for it to work.

Comment: You'll miss the title for "Reverend Martin Luther King Jr." and "Doctor Suess"...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just change your regex to :

```
my $re = qr/(\w*\. |)(.*)/;
 add alternation --^
```

Answer (score 4):

In general to make part of a match optional you use ?, on a `(?:   )` group if necessary.  Just using ? after a capturing group will leave that capture variable undef if omitted, but you can use a non-capturing group inside the capturing group:

```
/((?:\w*\. )?)(.*)/;
```

Answer (score 1):

To address the problem in another way, [Lingua-EN-NameParse](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Lingua-EN-NameParse/) might help.